# How to best serialize a java.awt.Image?

Tags: java, image, serialization

I have a Serializable object which is supposed to hold a java.awt.Image as its member. How should I go about serializing it?
*(Edited from a not so clear first version, sorry.)*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ImageIcon implements Serializable and it can be used to wrap an Image class

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Comment: Just be aware:

Warning:  Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases.

Comment: i tried....but got an error....
nested exception is: 
 java.io.EOFException

see the question i've posted...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117626/java-rmi-passing-imageicon-objects

Comment: While this solution works it seems to make very large serialised files. A work around is to keep the files intact on disc and save a reference, copying the image to a location relative to the serialised file.

Answer (score 2):

javax.swing.ImageIcon, as a part of Swing, does not guarantee to have compatible serialised form between versions. However, you can cheat and look at its readObject and writeObject code - find width and height, grab the pixels with PixelGrabber. I'm not entirely sure that covers the colour model correctly. The obvious alternative is to write a real image format with javax.imageio.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of.  I believe you need to write your own serializer for it to basically save out the width, height and pixel values...  Or write it out to the stream as a PNG or something