# Allow a Java Application User to import images to be displayed within the program

Tags: java, import, filestream, image

Basically, the functionality I want is for a user to use a file choose to import an image into the program and then that program be able to display that image. I then want this image to be able to be serialized and unserialized as the program is stored between launches.

As a sub question, whats the best way to display multiple images, is there a build in component or something similar I will I have to make something.

Thanks

Comment: *"..I want .. I then want .."* I want a pony.  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  I mean *besides* (effectively) asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.  *"As a sub question,"*  What was the main question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the image loaded into an Image object, just store that as a member of the class that wants to show it, and use drawImage() during that component's paintComponent() method.

If you use an ImageIcon, then as given in this question:

[How to best serialize a java.awt.Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139996/how-to-best-serialize-a-java-awt-image)

you have your technique for serialization (note the warnings).