# java rmi passing ImageIcon objects

Tags: java, rmi, imageicon

I m making an `rmi client server based program` which is suppose to `pass Image object through remote object interfaces`. **The Client receives an Image from the Server**.

Following is my code....

**At Client**

```
       public class ImageReceiver
       {
                  public static ImageIcon imageicon;

                  public static void main(String Data[])
                  {

                         imageicon = new ImageIcon(url);
                         imageicon=remoteObject.getImageFromServer();
                  }

        }
        // The Details regarding the binding of remote objects are excluded since they are worling fine...
```

sendImage is an interfacing method implemented...

```
        public ImageIcon getImageFromServer() throws RemoteException;
```

**At Server**

```
           public ImageIcon getImageFromServer()
           {
                  ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("local url specified");
                  return ic;
           }

         // Much of the Exceptions and other binding details are excluded for simpicity.....
```

Now the problem is, i m getting an error called

```
          java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return
          nested exception is: java.io.EOFException
```

Now, Actually i don't have much of any idea how it came...
The two major doubts I have is....

***Is it possible to send ImageIcon objects through rmi...?? If yes, What could be probably the mistake here. If not, does there exist any simple way to pass Image based objects as parameter through rmi...??***

**I've also heard somewhere that javax.swing.ImageIcon is serial....but it's not happening in my case**

Comment: How are you executing client and server? ImageIcon implements Serializable so it can be sent over the network, but in your case there seems to be a problem with deserialization. From the documentation of ImageIcon: "Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing." Do your client and server use the same version of Swing?

Comment: well....yes...i m running it on localhost........

Comment: Simple experiment: try replacing `ImageIcon` with something else, say `String`. Do you still get the same exception?

Comment: i tried it with string..it worked...but the problem came when i tried ImageIcon......

Comment: Well, how about using that then? Return the local url you use to construct the ImageIcon on server-side, instead of the ImageIcon. Now, you use that string to construct the ImageIcon on client-side (instead of transmitting it). Should work if the URL can also be accessed by the client.

Comment: @joergl that would be fine if we are running it on a localhost.....but then...if we are implementing this program on two systems......this won't do...

the local url would be different rite...??

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem occured...when i tried to pass ImageIcon object through RMI....

After a long checking....i found the url i specifed was incorrect.....

it happens...the complier in this often shows Unmarshall exception exactly as you shown.......

try checking your local URL.....

Comment: you got it right....i had a small url specification....but still don't understand why this showed Unmarshal exception as it has nothing to with Serialization....i believe...