# using ImageIcon in RMI

Tags: java, rmi, imageicon

Well i've got a simple doubt regarding the behaviour of instance of a java.swing.ImageIcon class.

Now it is based on RMI Client server operation......

Suppose there exist a **jpg file** called `A.jpg` in ***server computer***.
Now on retrieving it using

```
           // At Server...
           ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("C://server_image_folder//A.jpg");
           return ic;
```

and then using it in client with the function

```
           // At Client....
           // same variable name used for simplicity....
           System.out.print(ic);
```

**We'll observe here that it prints the URL of the image file in the server computer..**

*Here, for eg: -*  `C:/server_image_folder/A.jpg`

So my question is just simply....

```
  Will it cause any trouble since such URL don't exist in client computer ?
```

such problem cannot be observed in a a situation like ***localhost*** since both share the same URL( i believe ).

But, ***What about the condition when both programs are implemented in separate computers***....??

Comment: *"i can't practically test the situation...."* How is it practical to develop RMI based code without two computers or an environment that can emulate two?

Comment: `new ImageIcon(".../../A.jpg");`  BTW - `.` means current directory, `..` means parent directory, but what does `...` mean?  It is new to me.

Comment: it's just to show whatever directory u are in...that's all....

buddy the problem is simple.....
imageicon instance contains the url of the image at server computer...but u bring the instance to client using rmi...that URL doesn't exist(since u have brought it to a different system)....so will create any problem.....??

Comment: Duplicate of own post [java rmi passing ImageIcon objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117626/java-rmi-passing-imageicon-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't cause a problem, but may result in some confusion. The constructor that you're using treats the single arg as both a file name and a description. The `filename` field is transient, so it is not part of the serialized data. However, the `description` field is not transient and will be part of the serialized data. Since the `toString` method will return the `description` field if it's non-null, it might lead you to think that the file name has been retained as well, but it hasn't.

Comment: so in short you are saying.....it won't cause any problem....and the printed string which i found is just the description and nothing to do with the URL.....i'll get the image as i wanted in a scenario implementing client and server in separate systems.....

is that so....??

Comment: That's correct. ImageIcon uses its writeObject and readObject methods to maintain the underlying image's width, height and pixel data.

Comment: well...thanks...buddy...i'll proceed...hope it's correct....have a tick from my side...Also Please vote up my question if u feel it good's enough..