# Writing multiple objects to file

Tags: java, file, bitmap, io, outputstream

Today I am trying to write multiple objects to a file. My objects are two String ArrayLists, one Double ArrayList and a Bitmap. I can write all the ArrayLists fine and retrieve them the other end, but when I add the picture into the file I get Stream Corrupted Exceptions. Is this because I'm cramming too much into one file and the bytes are being jumbled?
Here is my write:

```
try {
    fos = openFileOutput(s, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        selectedImage = ((BitmapDrawable) addRecipeIcon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);

        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(Ing);
        oos.writeObject(IngN);
        oos.writeObject(Step);

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
```

When I write the Bitmap as well as the Lists I notice on DDMS that the data has been written (bitmap+lists) but it doesn't come out the other side.

Logcat:

```
W/System.err(10187): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
W/System.err(10187):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2109)
W/System.err(10187):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
W/System.err(10187):    at com.ollygrov.doughpro.Cal.myRecipe(Cal.java:808)
W/System.err(10187):    at com.ollygrov.doughpro.Cal.setDoughInfo(Cal.java:1350)
W/System.err(10187):    at com.ollygrov.doughpro.Cal.onCreate(Cal.java:198)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err(10187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
W/System.err(10187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err(10187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err(10187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err(10187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
W/System.err(10187):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: for reference.

I achieved what I wanted, to write a Bitmap, two ArrayList and one ArrayList by first serializing the bitmap into a byte[], writing each object in a specific order through the ObjectOutputStream, then loading in the same order the other side. My order was:

```
writeObject.byte[] (Bitmap),
writeObject.ArrayList<Double> (Ing),
writeObject.ArrayList<String> (IngN), 
writeObject.ArrayList<String> (Step),
```

then

```
byte[] b = readObject.byte[],
List 1 = readObject.ArrayList<Double>
List 2 = readObject.ArrayList<String>
List 3 = readObject.ArrayList<String>
```

Comment: why don't you create new class to hold all objects and store the new object instead of multiple object in single file /

Comment: Can you add different types to the class? Such as a bitmap and double and string Lists? I can see how it would be straightforward with one type of object but multiple confuses me

Comment: you can create variable in any type in class

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `ArrayList<Object>` or similar with the objects you want to write to the file and then cast back to the appropriate format afterwards. I don't have an Android to test this on, though.

Comment: Thanks, would it work with a bitmap, string and double Lists all in the same List though?

Comment: yes, every class derives from an object, so it would work. But don't forget to check with the `instanceof` operator before you cast to avoid exceptions. Add your String and double lists to the master list first.

Comment: When I add the Bitmap to the List and save, it says it's unserializable?

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember that I once had that same problem - check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139996/how-to-best-serialize-a-java-awt-image

Comment: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=32308 also has a nice explanation of how to serialize an image